# Material-UI: the key `field` provided to the classes prop is not implemented in undefined

Tags: material-ui

```
Material-UI: the key `field` provided to the classes prop is not implemented in undefined.
You can only override one of the following: pageFilter,topContent,title,toggleFilters,fields,topFields,actions,close,action,resetBtn,submitBtn,submitIcon,bottomContent,bottomFields.
```

This error occurs each time , when I use options and pass withTheme property :

```
withStyles(styles, { withTheme: true })
```

**styles.js**

```
export default function() {return {field: {width: 160}}}
```

How to pervent this issue ? If you need additional info , pls let me know

Comment: Hey Andey, did you managed how to fix this warning?

Comment: I've deleted this option, increased material to the last version and then for getting theme I've used useTheme hook, and for making styles, I've used makeStyles ( const useStyles  = makeStyles(styles) ) and then in component => const classes = useStyles()

Comment: hope it will help you